# What is the subtle error here?

Tags: javascript, html

I give up. This seems so trivial, but consistently doesn't work in any browser I've tried (IE8, Firefox 17). I can prove that javascript is enabled and works fine on other pages using it, but after 4 seconds, this always behaves as if javascript is disabled, and redirects to the "nojava.html" page. Why?

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="4;url=nojava.html">
<title>Test Page</title>

<script language="JavaScript">
function CheckJava() {
  timerID = setTimeout("after3sec", 3000);
}

function after3sec() {
  window.location="intro1.html";
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="CheckJava()">
<p>Test text</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I fully expect to be embarrassed by the answer...

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Also "Java" and "JavaScript" are completely different things, for what it's worth

Comment: Are you trying to embed a Java applet?

Comment: 1st off it burns my eyes that it says checkJava. Haha. Second I'm thinking the issue might be the set timeout. Every time I call it, I always have to say setTimeout(function() {FUNCTOINAME()}, 3000)

Comment: @DavidRichard, Or simply the function name... Read my answer for an example. You just wrap the function with a pointless function.

Comment: To me, these don't even need to exist in two different functions.  Why not just use `window.onload` and write your function?  This seems like   a quick throwaway.  If you are going to do it like this, why not pass parameters in case you have to do this again for different page redirects??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use strings with `setTimeout` and define the function before you use it.
Change to:

```
function after3sec() {
  window.location="intro1.html";
}


function CheckJava() {
  timerID = setTimeout(after3sec, 3000);
}
```

BTW there are a lot better ways to check if javascript is enabled or not, like `alert('TEST')`.

Also read about the [drawbacks of Meta refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh#Drawbacks)

Comment: The order of functions doesn't really matter. For one, `CheckJava()` is called only when `after3sec()` is already parsed, and even if it weren't, declaring functions like that will ensure they're always available.

Comment: Function declarations are hoisted in JavaScript.  Where the function exists is trivial.

Comment: @SethenMaleno, the order was a tip it's not mandatory(as JSLint suggest) and the real problem was the string.

Comment: @gordon Understood, but it's perfectly acceptable to leave function declarations as they are.  Calling people out for not putting them first in the code is nit picking a bit.

Comment: I knew I'd be embarrassed. Now I have to explain how it is that another page uses setTimeout with strings and works fine...

Answer (score 3):

The subtle error is that, if you pass a string to [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout), it will evaluate the string as JavaScript code.  Now,

```
after3sec
```

*is* valid JS code, but it only returns a reference to the function named `after3sec` (and then discards it, since you're not doing anything with it) rather than actually calling the function.

To fix it, just append a pair of parentheses to the function name:

```
setTimeout( "after3sec()", 3000 );
```

or, better yet, do as gdoron suggests and just pass the function reference directly to `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout( after3sec, 3000 );
```

In fact, you could even do it without using a separate function at all:

```
function CheckJava() {
    timerID = setTimeout( function () {
        window.location = "intro1.html";
    }, 3000 );
}
```

or, using the stringy style:

```
function CheckJava() {
    timerID = setTimeout( 'window.location = "intro1.html";', 3000 );
}
```